# Combinatorics: Distinct Award Distribution Problem

Tags: combinatorics

> Five separate awards (best scholarship, best leadership qualities, and so on) are to be presented to selected students from a class of $30$. How many different outcomes are
>   possible if:
>
> a) a student can receive any number of awards?
>
> b) each student can receive at most one award?

The common answer seems to be $30^5$ for part a, and $30.29.28.27.26$ for part b. What I really have a hard time understanding is since the awards are distinct they also impact the way the combinations are computed. In other words if one of the students if named "Joe Schmo", Joe Schmo with best leadership award is different than Joe Schmo with best scholarship and we cannot just multiply away all the students $5$ times.

Also, the answers $30^5$ and the other ones were obtained from the official solution manual to a certain book, so this also adds to my confusion.

Comment: Are you aware that the best answer, in your opinion, should be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

a) Think of it the following way: We have actually sorted the awards beforehand, and then gave them one by one. We first started with the best leader award, which under 30 people, let's say, Joe Schmo got. Then we got to best dressed and this goes to Jane Doe among again 30 candidates. And so on. If we had not sorted the awards beforehand, (i.e. the awards are not distinct), then we would have counted the case that Joe Schmo and Jane Doe each get one award twice. So what we are doing here actually is correct.

b) Same story, except Joe Schmo leaves the room as soon as he gets his award, which means there are 29 candidates for the award that Jane Doe got.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The awards are distinguishable (let them have numbers $1,2,3,4,5$).

**a)** (a student can receive any number of awards)

For award $1$ there are $30$ possibilities.

The same is true again for award $2$ so there are $30^2$ possibilities for the awards $1,2$.

This goes on, and there are $30^5$ possibilities for $5$ awards.

**b)** (each student can receive at most one award)

For award $1$ there are $30$ possibilities.

The person who received award $1$ cannot receive award $2$ so there $29$ possibilities for award $2$, so that there are $30\cdot29$ possibilities for award $1$ and $2$.

This goes on resulting in $30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot27\cdot26$ possibilities for $5$ awards.

---

**2)** The awards are not distinguishable.

**a)** (a student can receive any number of awards)

If for $i=1,2,\dots,30$ pupil $i$ receives $a_i$ awards then the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers with: $$a_1+\cdots+a_{30}=5$$So to be found is the number of such sums. This can be done with stars and bars, leading to $\binom{5+29}{29}$ possibilities.

**b)** (each student can receive at most one award)

$5$ different pupils must be selected for receiving the awards. That gives $\binom{30}{5}$ possibilities in total.